# Converting .class file back to text

Tags: java, javac

Alright, I was playing around, making a TicTacToe game in Java and when I finished, compiled, made sure everything worked I tried to copy the files to another directory using the cp command. It took me a few tries to get the arguments right but I succeeded in the end. In the process, however, I did something and now my .java file is binary? Well, it starts with:

cafe babe 0000 0033 006a 0a00 1e00 3207

and then proceeds with similar things 140 lines downwards. Is there a way to revert it back to text?

Comment: You use a decompiler. (Or if you're crazy you open the [class file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) and convert it by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still have the `.java` file. if you want to decompile your `.class` file, download the decompiler from the following link and open your `.class` file in the decompiler

http://jd.benow.ca/

Answer (score 4):

The .java file is the source file. The .class is the java compiled file.

So there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Uhm, what if the .java file is the same?